# Match an underscore instead of ident in macro

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

I'm creating a macro that matches two expressions and an identifier. I would like to be able to ignore the identifier if it's not needed, but the compiler seems to complain if I use `_` there.

My macro:

```
macro_rules! if_some {
    ($x:expr, $id:ident, $expr:expr) => {
        match $x {
            None => None,
            Some($id) => Some($expr),
        }
    };
}
```

What I'd like to do:

```
if_some!(obtain_an_option(), x, do_something_with(x))
```

and

```
if_some!(obtain_an_option(), _, do_something())
```

The second call fails.

I worked around it by defining a second macro `if_some_!` that doesn't receive an identifier (I could not use a second pattern either). I'm sure there's a way to say "here accept an identifier or just `_`.

Maybe there's already a macro/function for this (like `Option::map` now I think about it)... nevertheless it'd be nice to now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option::map` seems to be the best solution for this particular problem, but when you really need a macro which expect both idents and `_` as a pattern, you can also use the `$p:pat` fragment. The fragment of course accepts a broader range of patterns like `(ref x, y)`, but typically this will be acceptable.

```
macro_rules! if_some {
    ($x:expr, $p:pat, $expr:expr) => {
        match $x {
            None => None,
            Some($p) => Some($expr),
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", if_some!(Some(12), x, x + 1)); // Some(13)
    println!("{:?}", if_some!(Some(12), _, 1)); // Some(1)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to add a second arm that matches an underscore:

```
macro_rules! if_some {
    ($x:expr, _, $expr:expr) => {
        match $x {
            None => None,
            Some(_) => Some($expr),
        }
    };

    ($x:expr, $id:ident, $expr:expr) => {
        match $x {
            None => None,
            Some($id) => Some($expr),
        }
    };
}
```

And, yes, this sounds like you just want `Option::map`.